# IOS Phonegap App swipe from the edge to back

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, phonegap-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

I am making a phonegap hybrid app and I want to implement IOS native gesture of swipe from the screen edge to go back to previous page, but I am unable to find it how exactly should I implement it in my application. I tried to do with jquery but I can't seen to figure it out. Is there any alternative that I can in my application?